# How to modify existing column value on a DataBound in GridView using if else

Tags: c#, gridview

I use data source to populate the grid view. I need to be able to se every column that its value equals to 01/01/00 to nothing.

Here is my code and the image of the values:

The GridView with no border lines. 
 What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed that these are columns 9 and 10? I had a problem once where they changed the numbering. You might want to reference the column header name.

Comment: Also try using row.cells[x].value = "" instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: DO NOT PASTE YOUR CODE IN AN IMAGE.

Secondly, `Equals` method is supposed to check whether the value is equal to the one you pass in parameter. Intstead of that, use `row.Cells[9] = "";`

Comment: Ok I will not, next time.